# Interfaces, Parameterized Types and Collections

Tags: java, generics, collections

This is probably a java 101 question. But I've been away from java for ten years, so it's new to me.

1. I have 3 classes: Dog, Cat, Mouse
2. Each has its own ArrayList
   e.g., ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
3. Dog Cat and Mouse implement AnimalInterface (which has methods such as getFurColor() and setFurColor(Color c)).
4. I have a method called, say, changeFurColor(ArrayList <AnimalInterface>list).
5. Moreover, changeFurColor() sorts the input ArrayList  using a comparator that implements <AnimalInterface> so I need this parameterized type  in my changeFurColor() method.
6. I call the method with changeFurColor(dogs);

*However, this won't compile. The type <Dog> does not match the type <AnimalInterface> even though the former implements the latter.*

I know I can simply use ? as the type for the changeFurColor argument and then cast or do instance of within the method as a check, but then I can't sort the list with my comparator (and it seems silly to have 3 different comparators).

I can't type all ArrayLists with <AnimalInterface> because I don't want to risk a dog in with the cats.

I am sure there is a simple solution, but none of my books provide it and I can't find it online

pseudoCode:

```
public interface AnimalInterface
{
    public Color getColor();
    ......
}

public class Dog implements AnimalInterface
{

}
public class Cat implements AnimalInterface
{

}

public void example()
{
    ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
    ArrayList<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
    ArrayList<Mouse> mice = new ArrayList<Mouse>();
    changeFurColor(dogs)

}

public void changeFurColor(ArrayList <AnimalInterface> list)
{
    ... ..

    Collections.sort(list, MyAnimalFurComparator);

}


public class MyAnimalFurComparator implements Comparator<AnimalInterface>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(AnimalInterface o1, AnimalInterface o2)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

*UPDATE*
changeFurColor(dogs) does not compile

Comment: You can use backticks `\`` to surround code snippets in your question. You'll be able to render `<brackets>` more easily.

Comment: As @SotiriosDelimanolis said it, post your code man. It will be less to write for you, and easier for us to answer

Comment: The problem has to do with generics and type erasure: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: @duffymo seems plausible

Comment: Yes it is to do with type erasure. But how do I deal with the problem?

Comment: The code is not very helpful. It is not clear which class contains the method, and you don't say where is the compile error

Comment: Generics aren't covariant; a `List<Dog>` isn't a `List<AnimalInterface>`, even if a `Dog` is a `ListInterface`.

Comment: `public static <T extends AnimalInterface> void changeFurColor(ArrayList<T> list)`

Comment: You finally gave a code demonstrating the error, next time do it from the beginning. @SotiriosDelimanolis gave you the answer, you need a type bound

Comment: Sorry @Dici, will do. Spent the last ten years working with concepts rather than the concrete so it takes some getting back to....thanks for the guidnace

Comment: May I ask how I then construct the Comparator  MyAnimalFurComparator  as it won't compile as it currently stands?

Comment: `new  MyAnimalFurComparator()`?

Comment: OK, I see why I will only ever post real code in future. Psuedo code simply obfuscates the question. I'll take it from here and thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct answer (for neophytes that follow me)

Credit goes to Solitirios for his comment on the question.

```
public static <T extends AnimalInterface> void changeFurColor(ArrayList<T> list) –
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues in the design.I'd need the exact code to tell what's exactly wrong, but The possible errors are:

1. You are not implementing the AnimalInterface method in the animal classes (Dog,Cat..), the method need's to be implemented explicitly:

   ```
   class Dog implements AnimalInterface{public Color getColor(){return new Color();}}

   class Cat implements AnimalInterface{public Color getColor(){return new Color();}}
   ```
2. You are passing a Comparator class, insteads of a instance in the Collections.sort method:

   ```
   Collections.sort(list, MyAnimalFurComparator);
   ```

   You need to change it to this:

   ```
   Collections.sort(list,new MyAnimalFurComparator());
   ```
3. Also the compare method of your MyAnimalFurComparator should return an int

Comment: thanks, it was pseudo code. The actual code was in several different classes so it would have been complicated and confusing.

=